# Чтение из файла txt и вывод в массив. Php

Tags: php

Привет, как вывести данные из файла в массив?

Название файла: **sitemap.txt**

Содержание файла:

```
http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap1.xml
http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap2.xml
http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap3.xml
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вышло так:

```
$sitemap = array(
    'Site 1' => 'http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap1.xml',
    'Site 2' => 'http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap2.xml',
    'Site 3' => 'http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap3.xml'
);
```

Спасибо большое...

Answer (score 4):

```
 $fileData  =   mb_split("\n",file_get_contents("sitemap.txt"));

 foreach ($fileData as $rowNumber=>$site)
    echo "Site ".($rowNumber+1)." => ".$site."<br>";
```

Comment: Скрипт выводит инфу, но немного не так как хочется...

$sitemap = array(

    'Site 1' => 'http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap1.xml',

    'Site 2' => 'http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap2.xml',

    'Site 3' => 'http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap3.xml'

);


а у тебя


Site 1 => http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap1.xml

Site 2 => http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap2.xml

Site 3 => http://mydomaiin.ru/sitemap3.xml

Comment: А сами совсем ничего делать не хотим? Тогда нечего тут делать.

Comment: $fileData это как раз массив получается с ключами от 0 до N.

echo $fileData[0]; // первая строка
echo $fileData[1]; // вторя строка и тд.

Ну что бы получить именно такие же ключи, то что то типа этого, не тестировал, но должно по идее работать:

$keys  = array();
$fileData  =   mb_split("\n",file_get_contents("sitemap.txt"));
foreach ($fileData as $rowNumber=>$site)
 $keys[] = "Site ".($rowNumber+1);
$fileData  =   array_combine ($keys, $fileData);

// Вывод 
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($fileData);
echo "</pre>";